# Callback from registerForActivityResult not called when fragment is destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-memory

Let's assume a fragment has this `ActivityResultLauncher`:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment_layout) {

    companion object {
        private const val EXTRA_ID = "ExtraId"

        fun newInstance(id: String) = MyFragment().apply {
            arguments = putString(EXTRA_ID, id)
        }
    }

    private val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Timber.i("Callback successful")
        }
    }

...
```

This Fragment a wrapped in an Activity for temporary architectural reasons, it will eventually be moved into an existing coordinator pattern.

```
class FragmentWrapperActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var fragment: MyFragment
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFragmentWrapperBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFragmentWrapperBinding.inflate(this)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        fragment = MyFragment.newInstance("blah")

        supportFragmentManager.transact {
            replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        }
    }
}
```

And we use that launcher to start an Activity, expecting a result:

```
fun launchMe() {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MyResultActivity::class.java)
    launcher.launch(intent)
}
```

On a normal device with plenty of available memory, this works fine. `MyResultActivity` finishes with `RESULT_OK`, the callback is called and I see the log line.

However, where memory is an issue and the calling fragment is destroyed, the launcher (and its callback) is destroyed along with it. Therefore when `MyResultActivity` finishes, a new instance of my fragment is created which is completely unaware of what's just happened. This can be reproduced by destroying activities as soon as they no longer have focus (`System -> Developer options -> Don't keep activities`).

My question is, if my fragment is reliant on the status of a launched activity in order to process some information, if that fragment is destroyed then how will the new instance of this fragment know where to pick up where the old fragment left off?

Comment: "a new instance of my fragment is created which is completely unaware of what's just happened." - that's not how fragments work. Their state, including what activity results they are waiting for, is saved and restored when you go through process death and recreation.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Which makes this particularly odd as going through this with a debugger shows that the callback lines in question are being called when activities are kept in memory as normal, but are not when `Don't keep activities` is enabled.

Comment: If this is relevant, the fragment in question is currently wrapped in a very minimal activity (it just displays the fragment and that's it).

Comment: Sounds like you should include your very minimal activity in your question as well.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Activity added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minimal fragment is unconditionally replacing the existing fragment with a brand new fragment everytime it is created, thus causing the previous fragment, which has had its state restored, to be removed.

As per the [Create a Fragment guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic), you always need to wrap your code to create a fragment in `onCreate` in a check for `if (savedInstanceState == null)`:

> In the previous example, note that the fragment transaction is only created when savedInstanceState is null. This is to ensure that the fragment is added only once, when the activity is first created. When a configuration change occurs and the activity is recreated, savedInstanceState is no longer null, and the fragment does not need to be added a second time, as the fragment is automatically restored from the savedInstanceState.

So your code should actually look like:

```
fragment = if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Create a new Fragment and add it to
    // the FragmentManager
    MyFragment.newInstance("blah").also { newFragment ->
        supportFragmentManager.transact {
            replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment)
        }
    }
} else {
    // The fragment already exists, so
    // get it from the FragmentManager
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as MyFragment
}
```

Comment: You'll note that the guide also tells you how to [add your fragment via XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-xml), which would mean you wouldn't need to write any of this code at all - just a single `findFragmentById` if you want a reference to your fragment. That's generally a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Looks like I'm a bit rusty with some of the fundamentals after spending so long dealing with existing code. Thanks for the refresher.